# calculating similarity

Tags: sql, database, oracle, function, similarity

I have this code which calculates the similarity between two recipes - 
GENERAL EQUATION = similarity(r1, r2)
for example given a recipe with ingredients (chicken, haggis, cream, whiskey) which is 4 ingredients. being compared to another recipe of 5 ingredients (chicken, cream, mustard, garlic and onion). so the similarity will be (2*2/4+5) = 0.4.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 2*
(select count (*) from Ingredient i where i.idI in (
select distinct idI from RecpIngr where idR = r1.idR
INTERSECT 
select distinct idI from RecpIngr where idR = r2.idR))
/ ((select distinct count(idI) from RecpIngr where idR = r1.idR) +
(select distinct count (idI) from RecpIngr where idR = r2.idR) )
INTO similar_values
from Recipe r1, Recipe r2
WHERE r1.idR = 1 
and r2.idR = 2;
```

I need to edit the code above to be able to return the value given ny pair of recipe iD's.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  The best approach to getting what you want might be a very different query.  Also, what is `select distinct 2*`?  That does not look like valid SQL syntax.

Comment: If recipe requires two same ingredients (two portions of garlic) do you store them in two rows in RecpIngr? 
And more important - is it possible that recipe is also ingredient for next recipe? ( in this case you need hierarchical query )
Anyway here is data and your query [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/91c5e/1)  (I removed `INTO ...` as this seems to be part of some code block)

Comment: How is your data stored?, and  when you say compare, how are you planning to do that? . Take it from user as input or compare each row in a table with every other row ?,  are you looking at possible plsql code ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simpler approach.  I don't know if it will work just like this, but it should give you a better idea of the direction.  Let me know if any questions.

```
select count(i.idI), i.name
from Recipe r
   inner join RecpIngr ri on r.idR = ri.idR
   inner join Ingredients i on ri.idI = i.idI   
where (r.idR = 1 or r.idR = 2)
group by i.idI
having count(i.idI) > 1
```

just saw the update.  I didn't include the equation, but I think you might be able to figure that part out now.  Let me know if you need further clarification.